# Count number of text occurrences in column using Numbers

Tags: numbers

I am using Numbers to track data. I have a column that has comma separated values within each row (e.g. ‘I like cats, I hate rain, I like dogs’).

Is it possible to count the number of appearances for a specific phrase (e.g. ‘I like cats’) and report that count in a cell, for each phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COUNTIF(range,"=string")
```

Replace ‘range’ with the range of cells to count.
Replace ‘string’ with the string to match in the range. Asterisk is supported for a wildcard.

For example, to count the number of occurrences of ‘I like cats’ within cells in the A column, use `COUNTIF(A,"=*I like cats*")`.

Comment: I don't know if Numbers changed after you posted this but the current syntax on Numbers version 13.2 (7038.0.87) is now `COUNTIF(range;"=string")`, no asteriscs and the comma was replaced by a semicolon.

Comment: @Duck The syntax has not changed but I will clarify the use of wildcards in the answer. The asterisks are a wildcard, allowing for matching a substring in a longer string. If you want to match the exact string, omit the wildcards. The semicolon vs comma is a regional difference; en-US and en-GB use comma.